# Bluetooth TP-Link UB500 on Debian with kernel 5.18.0

Tags: linux, debian, bluetooth

I bought a TP-Link UB500 bluetooth adapter recently but haven't been able to make it work on Debian 11.

I've read that the driver for it was integrated in Linux 5.16. So I installed the latest kernel from backports, that is Linux 5.18.

```
$ uname -a
Linux tower 5.18.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 5.18.2-1~bpo11+1 (2022-06-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I checked the driver

```
$ lsmod | grep btusb
btusb                  65536  0
btrtl                  28672  1 btusb
btbcm                  24576  1 btusb
btintel                45056  1 btusb
btmtk                  16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             876544  13 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
usbcore               327680  8 xhci_hcd,snd_usb_audio,usbhid,snd_usbmidi_lib,88x2bu,uvcvideo,btusb,xhci_pci
```

And the usb device is said to use this driver :

```
~ ❯ usb-devices 

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2357 ProdID=0604 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer= 
S:  Product=TP-Link UB500 Adapter
S:  SerialNumber=E848B8C82000
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
```

But it still isn't working :

```
~ ❯ blueman-manager 
blueman-manager version 2.1.4 starting
blueman-manager 09.19.59 ERROR    Manager:118 on_dbus_name_appeared: Default adapter not found, trying first available.
blueman-manager 09.19.59 ERROR    Manager:122 on_dbus_name_appeared: No adapter(s) found, exiting
```

What should I do to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a newer kernel (6.1.0-18) but had the same problem. I solved it by installing the `firmware-realtek` package. This package has been moved from `non-free` to `non-free-firmware` repository starting on Debian 12, so you need to add it to your apt sources as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/736065/how-do-i-install-non-free-firmware-in-debian-12-bookworm)