# How do I install non-free firmware in Debian 12 (Bookworm)?

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, drivers, firmware

How do I install non-[free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) firmware using the [*advanced package tool (APT)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software)) in Debian 12 (*bookworm*)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Add the repository `non-free-firmware` to the APT software package sources in the [`/etc/apt/sources.list`](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList) file**, and do `apt update` with the `root` permission.

For example, set the content of the file to this:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
```

. And then, install firmware packages that you need, with the `apt install` command.

---

Starting from Debian 12 (*bookworm*), all non-[free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) firmware packages, such as `firmware-iwlwifi`, `firmware-amd-graphics`, or `firmware-misc-nonfree`, have been **moved from the repository `non-free` to their own repository, `non-free-firmware`.**

The Debian project has taken [the decision](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2022/10/msg00001.html) in October 2022 to create a new repository `non-free-firmware` and [include its content on installation media for Debian 12 (*bookworm*)](https://www.debian.org/devel/debian-installer/News/2023/20230219) to make things easier for the users. This means that the newer Debian 12 installer will automatically install such firmware along with the operating system if needed.

Comment: It also looks that Debian's own online search web pages have trouble finding any package that was moved in such section (at least as of today 2023-02-19).

Comment: Thanks for that. It's also worth noting that very often non-free packages from other sources (e.g. a manufacturer or somebody who's extracted the firmware from a Windows driver) will be in a .deb file to be installed by dpkg.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that to add the source in Debian 12 Bookworm, there is no need to directly edit the sources.list as the same thing can be accomplished in a desktop environment such as GNOME, by opening the "software" app and selecting the hamburger menu, under "software repositories" you can just check the (non-free) source which will add the non-free-firmware repository automatically.