# How to remove apt warning in Debian 12

Tags: debian, apt

After upgrading a couple VMs to Debian 12, I started having the following warning after running an `apt update` command:

```
N: Repository 'Debian bookworm' changed its 'non-free component' value from 'non-free' to 'non-free non-free-firmware'
```

Whilst this question is similar to [How do I install non-free firmware in Debian 12 (Bookworm)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/736065/how-do-i-install-non-free-firmware-in-debian-12-bookworm), it is not the same.

I don't use non-free firmware in my VM, how to get rid of the warning message without adding the non-free-firmware repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following loosely [Debian instructions](https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.html#non-free-split), create a /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/no-firmware.conf file, with the following content:

```
APT::Get::Update::SourceListWarnings::NonFreeFirmware "false";
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't use non-free firmware in my VM

But for the general audiences that get such warning and would like to get rid of it, disabling `non-free-firmware` may work for VM but may not be good for our laptops (e.g., for `firmware-iwlwifi`).

Per [release notes](https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#non-free-split),

> **To ensure installed non-free firmware packages receive proper upgrades**, changes to the APT configuration are required.

For *most* people, it'll be something like this:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
```

Comment: You are technically right, however that is the obvious part where the message disappears per the error message displayed *in English* by Debian.  The point of the question was how to find out how to get rid of that pesky message *when you dont really need non-free-firmware*

Comment: Totally understand, that why I emphasized that my answer is _"for the general audiences"_, on the question of _"how to remove apt warning in Debian 12"_, just _as titled_. And I emphasized _again in the end_ that my answer is _"for most people"_ to solve the problem as titled.