Broadcom Wifi not working with debian 12
I failed to install Broadcom wifi driver with the following methods:
$ lspci -nn | grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)

$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install linux-headers-amd64 firmware-linux-nonfree firmware-misc-nonfree b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer broadcom-sta-dkm
...
E: Unable to locate package b43-fwcutter
E: Unable to locate package firmware-b43-installer
E: Unable to locate package broadcom-sta-dkm

$ sudo apt-get update
...                                         
Reading package lists... Done
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'file:/run/live/medium bookworm InRelease' doesn't have the component 'contrib' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
...
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'non-free/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'file:/run/live/medium bookworm InRelease' doesn't have the component 'non-free' (component misspelt in sources.list?)

$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
...
E: Unable to locate package broadcom-sta-dkms

$ sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
...
E: Unable to locate package firmware-b43-installer

$ sudo apt install broadcom-sta-dkms
...
E: Unable to locate package broadcom-sta-dkms

$ sudo apt install b43-fwcutter
...
E: Unable to locate package b43-fwcutter

What did I miss?

It looks like you have some invalid entries in your /etc/apt/sources.list where the repos are listed.
You probably want something like
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main contrib non-free-firmware
instead.
See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/736066/197569.
